# coherent sheaves on the complement of an analytic set

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

If $X$ is a normal projective space (or a projective complex manifold) and $A\subset X$ and analytic set of codimension 1 in $X$ and we know that $H^q(X\setminus A,L)=0$ for all $q\geq 1$ and all line bundles $L$ on $X$, does it follow that $H^q(X\setminus A,\mathcal{F})=0$ for all $q\geq 1$ and all coherent algebraic sheaves on $X\setminus A$?

Comment: Is $q$ fixed, or is $q$ varying over all positive integers?